# Disabling the Import Button after the action is performed

Tags: jsf

I have a `importButton` that imports files:
Webpage Code:

```
<p:commandButton id="importBtn"
       action="#{importHandler.doImport}"
       value="#{i18n['admin.importFiles']}"
       onclick="importBtn.disable()"
       ajax="false"
       disabled="false" />
```

my aim is to disable or fade-out this import button once the import of the files is finished. [The process of importing works perfectly]
please any suggestions regarding how to solve this issue ?
Thank you in Advance !

Answer (score 1):

Define boolean (isDisabled) in your controller and assign true to it when action performed, and do this change in your button definition:
disabled="#{imporHandler.isDisabled}"
take care to return isDisabled value to false, when you need to use button again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and help
But the calling method is a Void, so it do not return anything>
AS, you informed, the button is used for one time and cannot be used again!!! 
any solution regarding this ???

Comment: even void, only change isDisabled to true inside this method to disable button.

Comment: Yeah, I did that but its working as the same as i explained in the previous Comment

Comment: try this:
onclick="document.getElementById('importBtn').disabled = true;"

Comment: onclick="document.getElementById('importBtn').disabled = true;"

adding this attribute to the Import Command Button, is not working

Comment: Is it possible to call 2 methods in the action attribute of the command button.

Comment: no, onclick is java script not java, what happened when you add onclick to your code?

Comment: yes I added to the Button property but its not working !

Comment: please tell me the error, note you already added onclick so you should replace

Comment: There is no error and no change is detected.
Thank you.

Comment: is the button disabled?

Answer (score 1):

Bind the `disabled` attribute to a backing bean boolean value that you will set to `true` at the end of the `doImport` method.

eg.

```
<p:commandButton id="importBtn"
    actionListener="#{importHandler.doImport}"
    value="#{i18n['admin.importFiles']}"
    ajax="true"
    disabled="#{importHandler.disableBtn}"
    update="@form" />
```

**ImportHandler.java**

```
private boolean disableBtn = false;
// + getters/setters

public void doImport() {
   // your code
   disableBtn = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, 
After implementing the way you said, its not getting faded-out but once again if i click the import Button there is another half screen display of the same window displaying the same page with faded-out import button.
Any Suggestions ?

Comment: After implementing the way you said, its not getting faded-out[but the importing was successful] and once again if i click the import Button there is another half screen display of the same window displaying the same page with faded-out import button. Any Suggestions ?

Comment: Does your action method return a `String` outcome?

Comment: Then, is there a specific reason to set `ajax="false"`?

Comment: Yes, because after clicking the import button the Ajax button helps to show the list of files getting imported on the same page and this step takes place in small space [Rectangular box].

Comment: You should precisely use ajax for such a behavior! I've edited my answer to ajaxify your upload action.

Comment: can you tell when you want to use import button again?

Comment: The Half-way display problem has been solved
First time when i click the import, there are no list of files that are getting displayed and i probably hope its running in the back ground,[Rectangular box is totally empty].
second time clicking the import button after few seconds, the import Button is getting disabled.

Comment: if no list of files, don't disable the button, so you can import again

Comment: @ Safwan: I need to use the import Button for the next time i upload the files by going back to previous page.[That's Working good]
I need to import only once, after that let the importButton get disabled.
{Main Theme, There is a uploaded file in page and i click the import button, there is a ongoing list of display of importing the files then once the import is finished, the Import Button must be disabled}

thanks a lot for your time @Zim, Safwan

Comment: Is there any other possible solutions that after i click the import button every time for importing the files, i can fade-out the button ?